# Equivalent concept for MDX as Keepfilters

Tags: powerbi, dax, mdx

we are using a multidimensional cube with power bi as the visual layer and i have some problems with a measure that should be quite simple but i dont know mdx/multidim very well.

How can i get the same result as (for contoso db) as a MDX Measure (that i can use in power bi in an equivalent way):

```
Sales Amount red Products = 
CALCULATE(
    SUMX(Sales, Sales[Quantity] * Sales[Net Price]),
    KEEPFILTERS('Product'[Color] = "Red")
)
```

I have a working measure that produces the correct results but it is too slow if more dimensions are shown in the power bi table:

```
    Create Member Currentcube.[Measures].[Sales Amount red Products]
as iif(  ( [Measures].[Sales Amount],[Product].[Color].&[Red]) <> 0 
        AND ([Product].[Color].currentmember is [Product].[Color].&[Red] 
    OR [Product].[Color].currentmember is [Product].[Color].[all]) ,
([Measures].[Sales Amount],[Product].[Color].&[Red] ) ,NULL)
```

Answer (score 1):

`KEEPFILTERS` ensures it doesn’t show Red sales when looking at other colors. The equivalent in MDX would be:

```
Create Member Currentcube.[Measures].[Sales Amount red Products]
as null;

Scope({[Product].[Color].&[Red], [Product].[Color].[All]});
  [Measures].[Sales Amount red Products] = ([Measures].[Sales Amount], [Product].[Color].&[Red]);
End Scope;
```

A `Scope` statement is a more efficient way of doing an IIF.

Answer (score 0):

We were able to identify all our issues with the setup we had.
We have a SSAS MD 2017 which has some problems talking to Power BI. The first one being the "format String" error that occurs like shown in this [post](https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2017/04/18/power-bi-ssas-multidimensional-and-dynamic-format-strings/)
We copied the profilers query and removed the "format string" line from the generated dax query. The performance was fast again (at least in ssms)

Second Problem is shown in this [post](https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2016/09/26/ssas-multidimensional-caching-related-performance-problems-with-power-bi-tables/). A friend of mine said that there is no fix for sql2017 from microsofts side but it is fixed for sql2019...